# Сеть и интернет через 1 устройство

Tags: сеть, wifi, роутер

Есть WI-FI роутер dir320 с последней фирменной прошивкой 1.3.3. Интернет приходит через pppt и раздается на 3 пк с вин ХП и 7.

Вопрос в том, можно-ли сделать так, чтобы одновременно раздавался интернет и ПК видели расшарные папки друг друга? Если можно то как?

Comment: @or8it, если Вам помог ответ - жмакните по галке слева под кулчаком вниз. ![alt text][1]  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/Qe5BY.png(взято из ответа @shaman888)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю проблема не в подключении и настройке роутера, а в отрытых портах самих рабочих станций. Для полноценного "функционирования" рабочей группы Windows и доступа к расшаренным каталогам машин внутри рабочей группы, необходимо что-бы на этих машинах были открыты некоторые порты. Скорее всего на всех машинах установлены фаерволлы (например CIS) которые эти порты закрывают.Вот ссылочка на то какие порты следует открыть:[Объединение в сеть домашних компьютеров, работающих под управлением разных версий Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/ru-RU/windows7/Networking-home-computers-running-different-versions-of-Windows#section_4)

Answer (score 0):

Почему нет? Какая разница компам в какой свитч втыкаться - в проводной или в безпроводной??? Если компы подключены к точке доступа (не важно по LAN или по WiFi) они уже должны друг друга видеть...

У меня на работе порядка 10% компов домена подключены к сети по WiFi, дома и жена, и я подключены к точке по WiFi. И на работе и дома все работает, все кому надо, видят всех, кого надо...

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос в том, выполняет ли свои функции роутер (как писали другие это должно работать и так), то самый простой способ это узнать:

```
ping <ip address>
```

и попробовать взаимно попинговать компы друг с друга.Если пинг идёт, а расшаренные папки не видны или как-то некорректно работают, это уже точно вопрос не в роутере, а в настройках ОС.

По настройкам шары, точно знаю, что есть некоторая несовместимость XP и 7, так что гугль в помощь, не забывайте про файерволы, брэндмауэры, антивирусы, которые могут препятствовать работе шар.

Answer (score 0):

В Win7:
Пуск - Панель управления - Центр управления сетями и общим доступом - Изменить дополнительные параметры общего доступа. Там в зависимости от того, как Вы определили сеть, к которой подключены (общая/домашняя или рабочая), жмете соответствующую стрелочку и проверяете, включено ли сетевое обнаружение и включен ли общий доступ к папкам и принтерам.
В WinXP, если мне не изменяет память, ничего такого делать не надо.
Да, еще проверьте, чтобы были открыты порты
Обзор ресурсов сети - UDP:137,138
Доверительные отношения - UDP:137 138 TCP:139